# How can I take the screenshot of a powerbi report using selenium in azure databricks?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pyspark, powerbi, azure-databricks

I have 3 Power BI reports. At present, to get the status of the report, we are checking all reports manually and inform heads the report is available through mail. I am trying to automate this process. I want to develop a script in databricks that automatically checks the status of these powerbi reports and send the status through mail.
Is it possible to implement the above scenario using databricks notebook? If so May I know how to do that?

My plan was to have the selenium driver installed in databricks and accessing the powerbi link via selenium. But I'm confused whether that's the right approach

Comment: What type of access you required? want to get a visual status or what are the KPIs that you are looking ?

Answer (score 0):

You get your reports to your mail by subscribing to that report.
Here are the steps for it.

Go To **Subscribe to report**

[image]

next **New subscription**

[image]

Now fill all the required details and click on **Save**.

**Subscription name**: Give a name to subscription.
**Recipients**: Add your mail id.
**Attach full report**: Select pdf or powerpoint format.
**Scheduled date and time**: Schedule a start and end date.
**Repeat**: Select the interval you want the report (Daily, Hourly...etc.)
**Scheduled time**: Select a time.

[image]

After subscribing to report you will get it in the given interval and at the scheduled date and time.

Output:

[image]

You can go to **More options** while creating subscription to add **Subject**, **Message** and report page.

For more information regarding using rest api to get reports refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/reports/get-report) documentation.